# Rails 3 simple custom post action for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a bit stuck with an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error on a form controller action that doesn't require a view since it's passing off params data to the controller and then the controller will post the API request.

```
# Newsletter controller

def index
end

def subscribe
  Gibbon.list_subscribe({:id => "my-list-id", :email_address => params[:email]})
end
```

In my routes:

```
# Routes
match "/subscribe", to: "newsletter#subscribe", :via => :post
```

View where my form lives

```
# newsletter/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag subscribe_path, class: "form", remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, :class => 'email', :type=>"email", :placeholder => 'Sign up for newsletter' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", class: "submit-button"%>
<% end %>
```

From the Newsletter index page there is a form and all I want it to do is send the request of the user's email address to my subscribe action

```
Error:

Started POST "/subscribe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-20 18:01:02 +1000
Processing by HomeController#subscribe as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZseTNfGI5151hk7fIhQH5/l536hc9/kdARf57352Y=", "email"=>"test-user@email.com", "commit"=>"Go"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1836ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/subscribe, application/subscribe with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Code/myapp/app/views"
):
```

The above is the error I'm receiving. I wanted to know how to pretend this template issue since the action doesn't require a view.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try redirecting after the action ends

Comment: Thanks Zippie.. it looks like this working. Is there a way to get redirect_to and flash messages to work with remote forms?

Comment: remote forms? you mean AJAX forms? Sorry if i'm missunderstanding something, but why would you need a remote form and a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
def subscribe
  if request.post?
    Gibbon.list_subscribe({:id => "my-list-id", :email_address => params[:email]})
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Success'
  else
    redirect_to some_place
  end
end
```

in your routes

```
post "/subscribe", to: "newsletter#subscribe"
```

Check your routes to double confirm

Comment: Thanks Nich!I'm understanding it more. Is there a way to redirect_to to the existing page instead of a different url but also get the :notice flash messages.

Comment: I see, if I remove the remote: true from the form, it will redirect to html pages, otherwise it's awaiting an ajax response?

Comment: u can just render a page if not redirect_to..yah,remote_to: is for ajax